# Page should not active when reload

Tags: sapui5

I am new to openui5 and developing web application. The page should not active when i reload the page. I am searching to do that using openui5 but i not getting idea about that.

Please help me anyone.

Comment: What do you mean by "page should not active"?

Answer (score 0):

Use some `session storage` to check whether the page is reloaded and if reloaded just kill it. for example assuming you want to kill the page:

```
    oStorage = jQuery.sap.storage("session");
    $(window).load(function() {
        if(!oStorage.get("is_reloaded")){
           oStorage.put("is_reloaded",false);
        }
         checkNoOfVisits();
    });

    function checkNoOfVisits(){
    if(oStorage.get("is_reloaded")){
     window.stop();
    }
    else{
    oStorage.put("is_reloaded",true);
    }
}
```